# django template: iterate and print just items with index for example 3,6,9

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there is some good way to iterate through list in django template and print just items with index which is for example 3,6,9 and so on...

Let's imagine I have list like this:

```
({'title':'first'}, {'title':'second'}, {'title':'third'}, .... {'title':'ninth '})
```

And in template I want to see just:

```
third
sixth
ninth
```

I know how to pass variable to template, I construct in a view, but just need the way how to iterate through them in template and print just what I want.

Or I need to construct list (or dictionary maybe) somehow differently? Using latest Django.

Thanks,
Ignas

Comment: That's not a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, sorry... Early morning... I have nested list and want to run through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`slice` filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) will allow you to slice a sequence just as you would in Python.

```
{{ mylist|slice:"2::3" }}
```

Comment: great! And if for example I want to run through all of the items, print them all, but apply different let's imagine css class to items with 3,6,9...

Comment: Then you'd use `cycle` and completely not this solution.

Comment: In the same time I found cycle filter and I'm about doing like this:

<li class="{% cycle 'one' 'two' 'three' as class %}">...</li>
<li class="{{ class }}">...</li>

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for notes and tips!